# intern PreExecutor 'isAbsoluteBaseUrl' undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

When I try to run my unit tests on a shippable build we're getting the following error from intern:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at <node_modules/intern/lib/executors/PreExecutor.js:199:15>
at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:393:15>
at runCallbacks <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:11:11>
at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:317:4>
at Object.run [as _onImmediate] <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:237:7>
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] <timers.js:345:15>
```

From a quick read around PreExecutor.js:199 it appears to be to do with the loaders & baseUrl config entries, which I have set as follows:

```
baseUrl: 'www/js',
loaders: {
    'host-browser': 'www/assets/requirejs/require.js'
}
```

Both seem to be perfectly valid (running & passing from my machine) - can anyone help point me in the right direction to find out what's missing/going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js added a `path.isAbsolute` method in 0.11.2 (2013.05.13); the version of Node.js on your other system is too old and does not have this method.

Unfortunately, team Node.js doesn’t bother to put information about API minimum versions in their documentation, so it wasn’t known at the time that this function does not exist in Node 0.10. Upgrading to Node 0.12 is the best way to resolve this issue; you may also want to open a compatibility bug on Intern if you are unable to upgrade.